# How can I implement kafka consumers in cljs app?

Tags: apache-kafka, clojure, clojurescript, shadow-cljs, cljsjs

I am working on a project that involves implementing a Kafka messaging bus for resiliency along with SQS in my app. The backend services are developed in CLJ and the frontend script is in CLJS. I have successfully implemented Kafka producers in the backend services, but now I need to implement Kafka consumers in the frontend application. The frontend application is a browser-based app that is using ClojureScript code as the script, and it is built with the Boot build tool.

The problem I am facing is that there is no perfect library to build a Kafka client in CLJS. I have considered wrapping a JavaScript library using Cljsjs and using it for my app, but I am having difficulty creating an extern file for the package. I am specifically trying to use the kafkajs 2.2.4 library, which can be found here: https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs.

I am aware that I could use shadow-cljs, but since the frontend is already developed in Boot and is in production, it would be a hassle to ditch Boot. Is there any way to use shadow-cljs with Boot? I know that shadow-cljs can be integrated with Boot, but the documentation is incomplete for Boot integration.

I would appreciate any help with creating an extern file for the JS library, or any guidance on integrating shadow-cljs with Boot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Feel free to comment on answers in your previous question if the answers were unclear.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is still the same as in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76226157/kafka-consumers-in-clojurescript-lang). Kafka is not frontend tech, the library you mentioned specially states "A modern Apache Kafka® client for Node.js". It will not run in the browser, regardless of build tool used.

Directly talking to Kafka from your Frontend seems like a bad idea on multiple levels. Maybe you want to implement some kind of relay mechanism, so that your backend acts as a middlemen and transfers messages from kafka to your frontend and back.